# How to avoid TextFormField from expanding on error?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a contact form for my website, and I can't figure out why the box get elevated on error, also the subject field get kind of compressed.

Any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

Here the code:

```
    return SizedBox(
      height: 460,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 900
          ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4
          : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                 ...
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 15),
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  ...
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter an email';
                    } else if (!isValidateEmail(value)) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid email';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            child: Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                maxLines: 20,
                ...
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error text makes the `TextInputField` larger. To display both fields at the same height, you have two options. Either wrap the field in a `SizedBox` or use a `helperText` with a single space.

You can find the original post with an example [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15400#issuecomment-475773473).

Comment: thank you! helperText did the job

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return Card(
  elevation: 2,
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 900
        ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4
        : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          //other options
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        TextFormField(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return 'email is not correct';
            } else if (!isValidateEmail(value)) {
              return 'email is not correct';
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        TextFormField(
          maxLines: 5,
          //other properties
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```